# Implementation of WS-ReliableMessaging for Axis 1.4

Tags: web-services, axis, ws-reliablemessaging

Do you know what implementation's of WS-ReliableMessaging for Axis 1.4 you have used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Apache Sandesha](http://ws.apache.org/sandesha/sandesha1.html) but I have not used.